# iOS Error 404 Remote Server not found error while sending message

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, openfire

First of all may be it can be a duplicate question, But due to curiosity I asked.

I am working on XMPP project with openfire in swift language. After few searchings I was successful to register a user. Now when I want to send a message to a user it throws me error 404, remote server not found. I don't know why this is happening.

Here is my code to send a message:

```
let sendToUser = strUserName + "@" + kAppDelegate.strJDomain
        let body = XMLElement.element(withName: "body") as! XMLElement
        body.stringValue = tv_Message.text!

        let thread = XMLElement.element(withName: "thread", stringValue: "messageThread")  as! XMLElement

        let messageBody = XMLElement.element(withName: "message") as! XMLElement
        messageBody.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "chat")
        messageBody.addAttribute(withName: "to", stringValue: sendToUser)
        messageBody.addChild(body)
        messageBody.addChild(thread)
        messageBody.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: (kAppDelegate.xmppStream?.generateUUID())!)

        kAppDelegate.xmppStream?.send(messageBody)
```

When I click on send it throws me an error:

```
SEND: <message type="chat" to="akhilesh@198.38.88.254"><body>Hello</body><thread id="3087B0E8-F926-426B-9B8F-15473F4404F2">messageThread</thread></message>


RECV: <message xmlns="jabber:client" to="gourav@vps.parkhya.org/411dv3ejcj" from="akhilesh@198.38.88.254" type="error"><thread>messageThread</thread><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></message>
```

I am using this port no.: 5222

When I am login to open fire it correctly showing me user online status and when I tried to send message it not works. I used few references but get no result. Apart from these I have setup open fire settings with all required plugins activated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are sending two different domain names for sender and receiver. You need to check which one will be correct and set it.

The correct one will be shown on openfire default home page i.e in server info. You can make corrections from there. After all this you not get these errors.